# How to fail RSpec test run if over a single test runs over time limit?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, rspec, grep

It's so easy to get lazy with ruby RSpec test suites and use the db way too much instead of mocking things out.  I'm trying to add a script in continuous integration builds that if any test runs over, say 5 seconds, the build should fail.

Here's the direction I'm going so far.

1. Use RSpec's `--profile` option
2. Grep the seconds out.
3. Fail if any seconds are over a certain limit.

This is the WIP command I have so far:

```
rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb --profile | \
tee /dev/tty | \
grep '[0-9] seconds ./' | \
grep -oEi '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | \
awk '$1 > 5.0' \
```

**Problems**:

- This will only `awk` out numbers.  If this were to fail in a build process, we would have no idea which file was the offender.
- Failing seems awkward from pipe.

I would do it like this (but there must be a better way):

```
if $(rspec spec... awk ...) > /dev/null ; then exit 1 ; fi
```

Out of the problems, I'm stuck the most on the first one.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might use just awk for all that. I'm not familiar with rspec output so I invented one to make sense.
Here would be a possible solution that would print everything but when it detects the line with X.Y seconds then it would evaluate if it should exit:

```
{
    echo "Running step 4."
    echo "Processing 4.0 seconds."
    echo "Running step 5."
    echo "Processing 5.0 seconds."
    echo "Running step 5.1."
    echo "Processing 5.1 seconds."
    echo "Running step 6."
    echo "Processing 6.0 seconds."
} | awk '{ print; 
           var=substr($0, match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ seconds\./), 3)
           if (var ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && var >= 5) { 
               print "Stop here! It took to long.", var; 
               exit 123 }
         }'
```

The result would be:

```
Running step 4.
Processing 4.0 seconds.
Running step 5.
Processing 5.0 seconds.
Stop here! It took to long. 5.0
```

There is a strange conversion issue with awk, but in your case might not be so critical.

You may replace the regular expression from inside `match()` with a better one for your output.